# .net create membership without username

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

probabaly a daft question but when creating a user using .net membership, can i exclude the username and just have the email as the 'username' like this?

```
Membership.CreateUser(model.UserName, model.Password, model.Email, ....
```

or leave blank...

```
Membership.CreateUser("", model.Password, model.Email, ......
```

cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you want the email as the username why not:

```
Membership.CreateUser(model.Email, model.Password, model.Email, ....
```

I'm not sure if an empty string for the username will be allowed (try it and see?) the docs are not clear, but as [the docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t8yy6w3h.aspx) state that a reason for failure can be `MembershipCreateStatus.DuplicateUserName`, you may only be allowed a single user with a blank name anyway...

Comment: Your example is the correct way to handle it.  It is kind of a pain though because you can't easily update the username using the Membership API.  Perhaps a custom Membership provider would be the best in this case?

Answer (score 2):

What I have done in this case is generate a random username upon account creation. Then, when it comes time to log them in, call Membership.GetUserNameByEmail(emailAddress) to get the username and use that to log them in.

I didn't want to put the email address into the username field due to users occasionally changing their email addresses.

Comment: yeah this is a suitable alternative.  using a guid for the user name is probably the way forward